# Revit Python Shell: How to get Type names of 'Pipe Types' Family with no instances in project?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

End goal is to pass the ElementId of the PipeType I want (Plex Wire) to Pipe.Create, but I don't know how to select the correct PipeType ElementId in a project with no Pipe instances to inspect.

In a test project, I have used Transfer Project Standards to bring over the PipeType I want to use, and manually created a few Pipe instances to inspect...

```
>>> import Autodesk.Revit as R
>>> types=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()
>>> elems=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
>>> for i in elems: print(i.Name)
...
﻿Default
Default
Default
Plex Wire
>>> for i in types: print(i.Name)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: Name
```

...but as I mentioned, I'd like to be able to use Pipe.Create from a project which contains the desired PipeTypes (from a Project Template), but has no pre-existing Pipe instances.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ElementType` `FamilyName` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/10de5c66-1b4b-9214-4036-27a6b24e5703.htm) [introduced in Revit 2015](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2015-api.html#4.05).

Before that, the simplest option used to be to use the temporary transaction trick: open a transaction, insert a dummy instance, grab the desired name, and roll back the transaction.

Comment: Jeremy,
Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, it just returns the Family Name 'Pipe Types'. I'm trying to get one level below this to the Type Name (Family Symbol Name) 'Plex Wire'. See below:

```>>> types[0].FamilyName
'Pipe Types'```

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Please upvote my answer, then. Thank you!

Comment: Would love to, but I have <15 rep :/ sorry.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that limitation. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I got Jeremy's 'transaction trick' to work (see below). Any critique on my code is appreciated, Thanks!

```
import Autodesk.Revit as R

pipeTypeNames={}

def GetPipeTypeNames():
    types=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()
    pipingSystemTypes=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipingSystem).ToElements()
    levels=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
    pipeDoc=doc
    pipeSystem=pipingSystemTypes[0].Id
    pipeLevel=levels[0].Id
    points=[]

    transaction=R.DB.Transaction(doc,'Get Pipe Type Names')

    transaction.Start()

    for t in range(len(types)):
        pipeType=types[t].Id
        points.append((R.DB.XYZ(0,t,0),R.DB.XYZ(10,t,0)))
        R.DB.Plumbing.Pipe.Create(pipeDoc,pipeSystem,pipeType,pipeLevel,points[t][0],points[t][1])

    pipeElems=R.DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()

    for p in pipeElems:
        pipeTypeNames[p.Name]=p.PipeType

    transaction.RollBack()

GetPipeTypeNames()
```

Comment: Congratulations! Glad it helped!